# How to code one jquery function for all AJAX links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework

I am using zend framework on windows. I want to implement ajax in my project first time. I searched for help and created a very simple ajax functionality.

**IndexController.php**

```
public function indexAction() {
}

public function oneAction() {
}

public function twoAction() {
}
```

**index.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/AJAX.js"></script>

<a href='http://practice.dev/index/one' class='one'>One</a>
<a href='http://practice.dev/index/two' class='two'>Two</a>
<br /><br />
<div id="one">one.phtml content comes here</div>
<div id="two">two.phtml content comes here</div>
```

**AJAX.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.one').click(loadOne);
    jQuery('.two').click(loadTwo);
});

function loadOne(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/index/one',
        success: function( data ) {
                    jQuery('#one').html(data);
                    }
    });
}

function loadTwo(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/index/two',
        success: function( data ){
                    jQuery('#two').html(data);
                    }
    });
}
```

Above code is working and loading data of one.phtml and two.phtml in 'one' and 'two' DIVs respectively when its link is clicked. You can see that I have to create separate jquery function for each link and also have to add new class for each link tag.

**What I want to do ?**:

I want to use only one jquery function for all AJAX requests and don't want to hard code **url** and **success** attributes in that function.

When I add "AJAX" class to any link tag then it should load content using AJAX.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `jQuery` over `$` for a reason?

Comment: Does it really matter? Maybe he is using some other js library with jquery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for simple loading of data in divs i would use the load method

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/AJAX.js"></script>

<a href='http://practice.dev/index/one' class='ajax' rel="one">One</a>
<a href='http://practice.dev/index/two' class='ajax' rel="two">Two</a>
<br /><br />
<div id="one">one.phtml content comes here</div>
<div id="two">two.phtml content comes here</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ajax').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();

       var target = '#' + jQuery(this).attr('rel');
       var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
       jQuery( target ).load( href );

      });
});
```

Use a single class to identify all links that should use ajax calls instead of their normal use. And add a `rel` attribute to those links that will contain the `id` of the container div..

Comment: Is that correct usage of the `rel` attribute, or would it make more sense to use the `data-` HTML5 attributes?

Comment: @Eric, you have a point. The usage i do is not the semantically intended by the w3 standards.. the `data-` would be more appropriate.. *although it would be invalid in non html 5 validators..*

Comment: @gaby another possibility would be to put something like "target:one" or "target:two" into the "class" value. Then the script could just strip out the "one" or "two".

Comment: @pointy, would that be considered valid html, having `:` in class names ? (*also, thanks for the edit..*)

Comment: I don't think there are many rules about what's in class names, but you could always use something else, like "ajax-", as the prefix. I've never heard of any problems caused by funny characters in class names.

Comment: @Pointy, indeed .. i just wondered about the `:` .. but validators are fine with it.

Comment: Thanks. Its working but one problem still exists. When I click any link, it is not changing url in browser's address bar. Anyway its good for me. I am learning AJAX step by step and its good step no.2 for me. My next step will be json and ajax combination.

Comment: @Naveed, have a look at this SO question/answer as it addresses the issue and a potential pitfall (*scrolling*) [Modifying document.location.hash without page scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

Simple and Nice. No Jquery required. Check this out:
[Bjax](https://github.com/KiraLT/Bjax)

Usage:

```
<script src="bjax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="bjax.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Finally, include this in the HEAD of your html:

```
$('a').bjax();
```

For more settings, checkout demo here: 
[Bjax Demo](http://bjax.6te.net/demo/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
function loadData(url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({url: url, success: callback});
}

loadData('/index/one', function( data ) {
    jQuery('#one').html(data);
})

loadData('/index/two', function( data ) {
    jQuery('#two').html(data);
})
```

To make this even more compact you could define the same callback for both and then have the handler decide which element the response data should be written to.

Comment: here #one and #two are also hardcoded. can we not also pass this? For example; array('one'=>one.phtml,'two'=>two.phtml);

Comment: Like I mentioned in the end of my reply, your response should contain something by which the Ajax event handler can tell what element it needs to apply the content of response to.

Answer (score 0):

Compact version:

```
$(function(){
    $('.one').click(loadOne);
    $('.two').click(loadTwo);
});

function loadOne(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#one').load('/index/one');
}

function loadTwo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#two').load('/index/two');
}
```