# PHP: Problem submitting form in AJAX/JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

currently I have following code:

**home.php**

```
<form name='myformname' id='myformid'>
    <input type='text' name='mytext1' value='abc'>
    <input type='text' name='mytext2' value='123'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'> 
</form>

<div id='textone'></div><div id='texttwo'></div>
```

**_home.php**

```
$arr = array( 'textone' => $_POST['mytext1'], 'texttwo' => $_POST['mytext2'] );
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

**ajax.js**

```
jQuery('#myformid').live('submit',function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '_home.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#myformid').serialize(),
        success: function( data ) {
            // TODO: write code here to get json data and load DIVs instead of alert
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Output on submit:**

```
{"textone":"abc","texttwo":"123"}
```

## Question

I want to load **mytext1** value in **textone** DIV and **mytext2** value in **texttwo** DIV using json data in _home.php

**Hint:** I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326614/how-to-load-more-than-one-divs-using-ajax-json-combination-in-zend/3326660#3326660) to do the same task on link click event. But how to do this on form submission ?

Thanks

Comment: Try: `alert(data['textone']);`

Comment: @sarfraz: it is hardcoded for a div. I want loop for all DIVs using json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just wanna parse that JSON and set the divs to the values it contains right?

```
var divs = JSON.parse(data);
for (var div in divs) {
  document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = divs[div];
}
```

(Previous poster's syntax is probably more like what you're after, and maybe is more cross-browser compatible, but doesn't include the JSON parsing.)

Since JSON is just a subset of JavaScript, you can just eval() it. JSON.parse() basically does that, but gives you assurances that if 'data' contains some nasty code instead of a simple object, it won't be evaluated.

Comment: I also answered the complete solution here.

Comment: If the Content-type header in the response is set to application/json, jQuery will automatically parse it in the data param passed to the success function.

Answer (score 1):

In the success function

```
for (prop in data){
    $('#' + prop).html(data[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my complete JS solution:

```
jQuery('#myformid').live('submit',function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '_home.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#myformid').serialize(),
        success: function( data ) {
            for(var id in data) {
                //jQuery('#' + id).html(data[id]); // This will also work
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data[id];
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```