# Ajax post return value

Tags: php, ajax

Im using Ajax to send values to a PHP script which writes some value to a database:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "action=vote_down&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
    url: "vote.php",
    success: function(msg) {
        $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut();
        $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);
        $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();                      
    }
});
```

As you can probably tell from the `action=vote_down` the script is for a voting script.

Im already preventing the user from voting more than once by logging there vote against there username and ID in `vote.php` and if there username and ID is already in the DB against the same post then I dont add the vote to the DB.

I personally think that querying the database on each page load to check if the user has already voted could be quite intensive, there are many places to vote on a single page.

So instead i'll show the user the voting option, but when they vote I want to some how return a value from `vote.php` to say they have already voted.

Any ideas for the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should put you in the right direction...

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-and-php-variables

I would parse back a boolean false if they have posted already, or the id of the vote if they were successful (for styling / adding the html message).

Answer (score 2):

Use [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

If this is your file to show the voting form:

```
<div id='voteform-div'>
 <form id='voteform'>
   Your form elements and a submit button here.
 </form>
</div>
```

Your JS code look like this:

```
jQuery('#voteform').live('submit',function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'vote.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "action=vote_down&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( messages) {
            for(var id in messages) {
                jQuery('#' + id).html(messages[id]);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

your **vote.php** should be something like this:

```
// Get data from $_POST array.

if( Already voted ) {

  // It will replace the id='voteform-div' DIV with error message
  $arr = array ( "voteform-div" => "you have already voted." ); 

} else {

 // Store vote in database

  // It will replace the id='voteform-div' DIV with confirmation message
  $arr = array ( "voteform-div" => "Yor vote is submitted. Thanks" );

}

echo json_encode( $arr ); // encode array to json format
```

For more detail on this look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506272/php-problem-submitting-form-in-ajax-json).