# How do I prevent the browser from jumping to an anchor when the URL's fragment identifier is changed to it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Modifying document.location.hash without page scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling)

I'd like to cancel the event, if possible, but I don't see any precedent for this. Assume for the moment that I'm constrained to using the same string for both my fragment identifier and the name of my anchor. I need to intercept the event and cancel it somehow.

UPDATE: This is a duplicate of [Modifying location.hash without page scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling)

Comment: There is some code on here that does it, I'll try and find it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling

Comment: Thanks, scoffey. It is indeed a duplicate of 1489624. I'll add a note to the description. If you know what further steps I should take to mark this as a duplicate, let me know. Thanks!