# Change location.hash without page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
    hash = hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
var node = $( '#' + hash );
if ( node.length ) {
  node.attr( 'id', '' );
}
document.location.hash = hash;
if ( node.length ) {
  node.attr( 'id', hash );
}
```

Im having trouble with the code above, which I grabbed from this article: [Modifying document.location.hash without page scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling), trying to temporarily replace the id of a div while I change the location.hash to said id. hash comes up with this error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: hash is not defined. I'm new to JS and need a little guidance! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line seems wrong:

```
hash = hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
```

Are you sure you defined the hash variable before it?

I think it has to be like this:

```
var hash = document.location.href;
hash = hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
```

and then the rest of code shouldn't cause the error

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you've properly defined `hash`.
- Make sure you also `return false` if you're handling the click event of an anchor.