# preventing scroll down on hash changes or a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifying document.location.hash without page scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling)

How to prevent scrolling down the page to the hashtag when the hash has changed? I tried the following method:

```
$("#button_bar a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //This was to prevent the hash scroll down behavior

    window.location.hash = this.hash; //This makes scroll down to the hash again

    $(window).hashchange( function(){ //this recognizes if the hash has changed
        recognizeHashTag();  //this identifies the hashtag and fires an ajax call
    });
});
```

The problem is when I quote `window.location.hash = this.hash`, it does not do anything. And when it is unquoted the hash behavior comes back again.
If someone has an idea thanks a lot.

Comment: yes that's not exactly a scroll. The hash is placed in the middle of the page and when the hash changes the page jumps to that point.

Comment: Have you tried sticking a return false at the end?

Comment: Have you looked at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling)?