# Cancel page scroll when using hash in links.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made tabs with jQuery. And I need to be able to link to exact tab. It's done.(code below) Problem I faced is that I can't prevent page scroll after switching the tabs. How can I disable scroll but still use hash?

```
<ul class="tabs group">
    <li>
    <a id="komp-link" class="switch" href="#komplekti">Komplekti</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a id="intern-link" class="switch" href="#internets">Internets</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a id="iptv-link" class="switch" href="#iptelevizija">IP Televizija</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="komplekti">content 1</div>
<div id="internets">content 2</div>
<div id="iptelevizija">content 3</div>
```

// Tabs Switch

```
 $('#komp-link').click(function(){
        $('#komplekti').show();
        $('#internets').hide();
        $('#iptelevizija').hide();
    });
    $('#intern-link').click(function(){
        $('#komplekti').hide();
        $('#internets').show();
        $('#iptelevizija').hide();
    });
    $('#iptv-link').click(function(){
        $('#komplekti').hide();
        $('#internets').hide();
        $('#iptelevizija').show();
    });
```

// Enable linking to exact Tab

```
if(window.location.hash) {

        var getHash = window.location.hash;
        console.log(getHash)
        $(getHash).show();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I found similar question but I didn't understand how to implement it in my case... Here it is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$('#komp-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

You should be able to simplify your code though..

```
<ul class="tabs group">
    <li>
    <a id="komp-link" class="switch" href="#komplekti">Komplekti</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a id="intern-link" class="switch" href="#internets">Internets</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a id="iptv-link" class="switch" href="#iptelevizija">IP Televizija</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="komplekti" class="tab">content 1</div>
<div id="internets" class="tab">content 2</div>
<div id="iptelevizija" class="tab">content 3</div>
```

...

```
$('.switch').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tab').hide();
    $($(this).href()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found decision. 
Best & easiest way is to use [Bens Almans jQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) - hashchange event.