# jQuery + CSS: How to scroll smooth, regarding a fixed header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'd like to use smooth scrolling on a onepager. On clicking a link, the depending section should scroll to the nav's bottom. Problem: the nav's position is fixed.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LNwmt/

**HTML**:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section5">Section 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section6">Section 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="section1">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>[...] Text [...]</p>
</section>
<section id="section2">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>[...] Text [...]</p>
</section>
<section id="section3">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <p>[...] Text [...]</p>
</section>
<section id="section4">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <p>[...] Text [...]</p>
</section>
<section id="section5">
    <h2>Section 5</h2>
    <p>[...] Text [...]</p>
</section>
<section id="section6">
    <h2>Section 6</h2>
    <p>[...] Text [...]</p>
</section>
<footer>
    Footer
</footer>
```

**CSS**:

```
nav { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: gray; 
}

section {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

section:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 200px;
}

footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: gray;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-200 // - 200px (nav-height)
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});
```

Does anyone know, how to make this code working fine? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This appears to work find in Chrome - items 4-6 won't scroll all the way up as the page length won't allow it.  What behavior would you like to see?

Comment: @dc5 You're right, the first items are working in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I'd like to have it working like in Chrome (most important!), browser-independent. 

The scrolling of item 4-6 should work as well. Maybe there's an additional offset needed.

Comment: It's the hash that is triggering the additional scroll.  Perhaps this post will help:  [Modifying document.location.hash without page scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Firefox, one fix for the jumping scrolling behavior is to change the location hash to one that doesn't exist in the document.

Changing your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 200 // - 200px (nav-height)
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            // Replace this with something that can be easily parsed and used by your code
            window.location.hash = '1' + target;
        });
    });
});
```

Seems to fix the problem:  [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNwmt/3/)