# how to make the page not reload after changing the hash?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="clickHash()">hash</button>
        <button onclick="clickCancel()">cancel</button>
        <div style="height: 2000px; width: 1000px; background: red;"></div>
        <button onclick="clickCancel()">cancel</button>
        <script>
            clickHash = function(){
                location.hash = "#test";
                window.scrollTo(0, 2000);
            }
            clickCancel = function(){
                location.hash = "";
            }
            handler = function() {
              console.log("hashchange fired");
            }
            window.onhashchange = handler;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I expect by the code above is that when I click the hash button, change the hash and scroll the page to the bottom, and when I click the cancel button, remove the hash. However, when the hash is removed, the page will jump to the top. I guess it might be because the page get reload or refresh when the hash changed.

Does anyone know how to make the page not reload after changing the hash?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gLCTB/) is the example.

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to remove the hash?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling

Comment: @isherwood thank you for your answer. I'll check whether it works for me.

Comment: @kaspermoerch In my application, I use the hash to determine if a picture is visible. Also, I have to set a button to set hash empty, which means no picture shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page does not reload. You're setting a new hash `""` which is equivalent to `"top of the page"` so the browser does what you tell him: jump to the top.

If you want to keep the postion you should recall `scrollTo()`:

```
clickCancel = function(){
  location.hash = "";
  window.scrollTo(0, 2000);
}
```

Comment: "" which is equivalent to "top of the page" make sense. Thank you.