# Auto scroll page at expanding last item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can be made auto scroll of content up when we expand last item on the page? This item is expanding but is not visible until we scroll.. I tried manipulating with css but it doesnt work. Overflow: scroll is enabled. Thank You

Comment: You could use Window.scrollTo(x,y) to explicitly change the scroll position.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Comment: yeah but it is easy when you have few of them but here is necessarity to get items from a table, a lot of them, so I don't know exactly positions where to take it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following approach

On item expanding event execute this:

```
location.hash = '#item_id';
```

Here **"#"** is mandatory

Comment: do you have maybe some example of this? I would appreciate this

Comment: Here's the good example with Smooth Auto Scroll
http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Smooth-Auto-Scroll-Tutorial

Comment: It's a good solution, not one I've ever used.
@Dinone Check out this question - he's setting location.hash and trying to make it not scroll, but it should still help if you want to use that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

try using JQuery Scroll.

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/satowan/8vqfxet7/