# Javascript change window.location.hash without scrolling, but still trigger CSS :target pseudo-class

Tags: javascript, html, css

As best I'm aware, there are two ways to change the hash at the end of the URL. `window.location.hash` and `history.pushState`. However, `history.pushState` [does not trigger the CSS `:target` pseudo-class](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83490) so that's out.

[An answer to "Modifying document.location.hash without page scrolling"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489802/148824) demonstrates a method to modify `location.hash` without scrolling, but this workaround fails to trigger the `:target` pseudo-class on the element with a matching ID.

Below is a simple example. Two links work as expected: `:target` is triggered and the tabs display, but they'll also scroll into view if necessary. Two links don't work: `:target` isn't triggered, but scrolling is prevented.

```js
(function() {
  function setHash(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var decoy = document.querySelector(".dummy-tabpanel");
    var tabId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
    var id = tabId.replace( /^#/, '' );
    var tabPanel = document.getElementById(id);
    
    decoy.style.top = document.body.scrollTop + 'px';
    
    tabPanel.setAttribute('id', '');
    decoy.setAttribute('id', id);
    
    window.location.hash = tabId;
    
    decoy.setAttribute('id', '');
    tabPanel.setAttribute('id', id);
    
    return false;
  }
  
  function setHashDirectly(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var tabId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
    window.location.hash = tabId;
    return false;
  }
  
  var tabLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
  
  for (var tabLink of tabLinks) {
    tabLink.addEventListener("click", tabLink.classList.contains('direct') ? setHashDirectly : setHash );
  }
})()
```

```css
.tabs {
  margin-top: 300px; // attempt to make scrolling necessary
}

.tabs [role="tabpanel"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs [role="tabpanel"]:target {
  display: block;
}

.dummy-tabpanel {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#one">one (doesn't scroll or trigger <code>:target</code>)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#two">two (doesn't scroll or trigger <code>:target</code>)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#three" class="direct">three (triggers <code>:target</code> but scrolls)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#four" class="direct">four (triggers <code>:target</code> but scrolls)</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="tabs">
  <div role="tabpanel" id="one">
    this is the first tab (won't display)
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" id="two">
    this is the two tab (won't display)
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" id="three">
    this is the third tab (should display)
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" id="four">
    this is the forth tab (should display)
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dummy-tabpanel"></div>
```

Is there some way to get the "best of both worlds," i.e. change the window hash *without* scrolling the page **and** have CSS `:target` triggered?

Note: I've tested this on Chrome 64 and Firefox 58 on OS X 10.13.

Comment: You can always just add a class or ID to each element and use css on that

Comment: So in other words, you wish to reveal hidden content with a link via `:target`,  ***but*** you don't want to jump to the `:target` destination?

Comment: @zer00ne exactly, but I'd like to avoid adding and removing classes or modifying inline styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `history.pushState` probably should update the CSS `:target` selector, since using the browser back and forward buttons to navigate back and forward after using `history.pushState` does indeed update it. It has [an open bug in webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83490), and there is [talk of standardizing the behavior to be one way or the other](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/639), rather than the current inconsistent behavior. If they choose to make it update the CSS, then your code will just work as-is. If they choose to make it not update the CSS, then browsers will have to change the behavior of the back and forward buttons to not update the CSS for entries created by `history.pushState`, or possibly any, which seems like an obviously wrong move.

So, your code may work without changes in the future, but as of right now you have to work around this by calling `history.pushState` and then navigating back and forward for the user. Here's a solution based on a [solution by laughinghan on GitHub](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/639#issuecomment-285452237):

```js
function pushHashAndFixTargetSelector(hash) {
    history.pushState({}, document.title, hash); //called as you would normally
    const onpopstate = window.onpopstate; //store the old event handler to restore it later
    window.onpopstate = function() { //this will be called when we call history.back()
        window.onpopstate = onpopstate; //restore the original handler
        history.forward(); //go forward again to update the CSS
    };
    history.back(); //go back to trigger the above function
}
```

Theoretically, this workaround will keep working even after they standardize the intended behavior.