# Utilizing back and forward browser buttons for web apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, webbrowser-control, unobtrusive-javascript

How do I use the back and forward browser buttons to navigate my javascript/jQuery web application?  I know I can do `window.location.href = 'this_url#placeholder'` and then perform the appropriate action.  But when I do that, the browser scrolls to the element with that placeholder id (or to the top if there wasn't one).  How do I get the browser to not scroll anywhere?  I've seen this on other sites like facebook, what's the appropriate mechanism for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `location.hash` instead of `location.href` the behaviour you specify shouldn't happen.

The HTML5 standard specifies new history features e.g. `history.pushState()` which offer a nice replacement for this, but not all browsers support it yet.

If you don't want to roll your own framework, there are a number of javascript plugins which offer this functionality all packaged up nicely for easy use across browsers with slightly differing implementations. For example [jquery history](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/history) will use the newer `history` options on browsers that support it and fall back to hash urls in browsers that don't.

Comment: +1 for the link to the History plugin. It's IMO by far the most elegant solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might answer your question:

[add a hash with javascript to url without scrolling page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439895/add-a-hash-with-javascript-to-url-without-scrolling-page)

Answer (score 0):

Just use placeholders that are not actually defined in the page. If you have

```
<a name="contents">
```

Then use

```
<a href="#contentsarea">Contents</a>
```

To activate the contents section. The browser only scrolls if the hashtag has an anchor in the page.

Comment: For me it scrolled to the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can add `return false` after that or `event.preventDefault`.

```
$("a#some_id").click(function(){
  // do something cool
  return false; // don't scroll to #some_id
});
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) for relevant discussion.

Comment: You misunderstood the question